# Ahorrar código en popovers de Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap

Sucede que tengo los típicos popovers que ofrece Bootstrap, pero estoy teniendo scripts para cada uno de ellos. Son 7, y sé que es una mala práctica repetir código. Pienso en que podría implementar un `for` para iterar solamente la función y solamente cambiar el contenido, pero realmente no sé cómo pensarlo. Intenté algo pero el contenido de los popovers siempre es el mismo. 
Adjunto código solo para 3 de los 7 popovers, ya que creo que es suficiente.

HTML

```
<div class="crs-area">
  <div class="popovers"><a data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="hover" class="pop-title">Titulo 1</a>
    <div id="popover-content" style="display:none;">
      <ul>
        <li>contenido 1</li>
        <li>contenido 2</li>
        <li>contenido 3</li>
        <li>contenido 4</li>
      </ul>
    </div><br/>
  </div>
  <div class="popovers"><a data-toggle="popover1" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="hover" class="pop-title">Titulo 2</a>
    <div id="popover-content1" style="display:none;">
      <ul>
        <li>contenido 5</li>
        <li>contenido 6</li>
        <li>contenido 7</li>
        <li>contenido 8</li>
        <li>contenido 9</li>
        <li>contenido 10</li>
        <li>contenido 11</li>
      </ul>
    </div><br/>
  </div>
  <div class="popovers"><a data-toggle="popover2" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="hover" class="pop-title">Titulo 3</a>
    <div id="popover-content2" style="display:none;">
      <ul>
        <li>contenido 12</li>
        <li>contenido 13</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .csr-area { 
    margin-bottom: 32px; 
  }

  .csr-area .accordion, .crs-area .popovers {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }

  .csr-area .accordion .title, .popovers{
    color: #333333;
    font-style: "MontserratBold";
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 18px;
  }

  .csr-area .accordion span{
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 18px 15px 18px;
  }

  .csr-area h2 {
    color: #ff0000;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
  }

  .pop-title {
    color: #333333;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  a.pop-title:hover, a.title:hover {
    color: #1BA6AF !important;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  ul {
    font-family: "MontserratRegular";
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
```

jQuery

```
    $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
      html: true, 
      content: function() {
            return $('#popover-content').html();
          }
  });

  $("[data-toggle=popover1]").popover({
      html: true, 
      content: function() {
            return $('#popover-content1').html();
          }
  });

  $("[data-toggle=popover2]").popover({
      html: true, 
      content: function() {
            return $('#popover-content2').html();
          }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumiendo que el contenido de tus etiquetas popover (**html**) es lo que quieres mostrar en tus popovers. Puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
   html: true, 
   content: function() {
        return $(this).html();
    }
});
```

No lo he probado, si no funciona puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
    $("[data-toggle=popover]").each(function(){
       var self = $(this);
       self.popover({
       html: true, 
       content: function() {
            return self.html();
        }
     });
    });
```

**Disculpa como antes te habia dicho no lo habia probado**
EDICION 1

Tu html deberia quedar asi para que coincida con lo que te pondré

```
<div class="popovers"><a data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-trigger="hover" class="pop-title">Titulo 3</a>
<div class="popover-content" style="display:none;">
  <ul>
    <li>contenido 12</li>
    <li>contenido 13</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Titulo 2

- contenido 6
- contenido 7
- contenido 8
- contenido 9
- contenido 10
- contenido 11

Aquí los cambios que hice fueron los siguientes:

1. Cambie el **data-placement** por cuestión de diseño meramente puedes usar el que tu quieras
2. Todos los **data-toggle** los puse con el mismo valor y no como antes que era incremental 1,2,...,n según tu logica usada en tu ejemplo.
3. Removí el atributo id del div que contiene lo que quieres mostrar en tu popover ya que concigo llegar hasta el con el selector de su clase, en este caso le puse **popover-content**.

Este es el codigo javascript

```
//Recorro todos los elementos que tienen el atributo data-toggle igual a popover
$("[data-toggle=popover]").each(function(){
    //Obtengo una instancia del elemento actual de la iteración
    var self = $(this);
    //Obtengo el html que quiero añadir aqui podras ver como busco por el nombre de la clase que le puse a todos los div que contienen el html que deseas agregar
    var content = $(this).parent().find('.popover-content').html();
    //En caso de que encuentre lo que buscas entonces configuras los popover como querias
    if(content !== undefined)
      self.popover({html: true, content: content });
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. No me funciona. Sólo me muestra el mismísimo título, y solamente del primer popover.

Comment: Les quité en el html el número del popover en el atributo data-toggle y ahora se muestra cada título correspondiente. Sólo necesito que se muestre el contenido.

Comment: No se porque no se muestra bien el segundo popover en el html de la respuesta, bueno es igual que el segundo lo unico que cambia es el contenido dentro del div que contiene la lista que deseas mostrar

Comment: La verdad que te esmeraste muchísimo en ayudarme, y efectivamente diste con la solución. Funciona de maravilla. Te agradezco muchísimo, Dariel! Gracias por compartir tu conocimiento. Saludos!

Comment: Para eso estamos aqui y me esmere porque sino me penalizan jajajaj na es un chiste :)